# Can Elementary OS 5 and 6 run in Alienware Area 51M laptop?

Tags: elementary-project

Can Elementary OS 5 and Elementary OS 6 in Alienware Area 51M?

My laptop is Alienware Area 51M, which is my main workstation. Currently it runs with Ubuntu 20.04 desktop 64bit LTS. But I plan to install Elementary OS 5 (or OS 6).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Elementary OS 5 and OS 6 should be able to run on the recent Alienware notebooks. That said, given that your hardware is pretty new, you will want to use OS 6 as it ships with the newer kernel that supports your processor (10th Gen Intel), Nvidia graphics card, network devices, and other hardware. OS 5 is based on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS so, while it may install, the hardware will not operate at its potential.

As you have already installed Ubuntu 20.04 on the notebook, be sure to note which devices worked out of the box and which ones needed a little attention after installation. You will likely need to repeat those same steps on OS 6.